# How to get correct resolution folder of F# Type Provider when referencing assemblies via #load?

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-scripting, paket

I'm writing a type provider which allows the user to supply a configuration file to it. I use the TP's internal configuration object to identify the `ResolutionFolder`, which I use to get the fully-qualfied path to the config file. Great.

However, when working with scripts, I use Paket's auto-generated load scripts to load in my dependencies. The file path looks like this: -

```
.paket
   |--.load
   |     |-- net452
   |           |-- main.group.fsx
   |--src
       |-- myscript.fsx
       |-- config.json
```

`myscript.fsx` contains my script code. `config.json` contains the configuration for the type provider instance that I'll create in the script.

Inside `myscript.fsx` I call `#load "..\.paket\.load\net452\main.group.fsx"`  to load in all dependencies (including my TP itself) which works fine.

**HOWEVER**

When I then try to initialise the type provider further down in the script: -

```
type MyTPInstance = MyTp<myConfig = "config.json">
```

I get an error which my TP catches and shows: -

```
The type provider reported an error: Unable to locate config file
"C:\Users\Isaac\Source\Repos\myRepo\.paket\load\net452\config.json"
```

In other words - it appears that because I've referenced my TP assembly from a script living in another folder, *that's* the folder that's used by FSI as the resolution folder - and NOT the folder of the script that's being run. I can prove this is the problem because if I copy the contents of the `main.group.fsx` into `myscript.fsx` directly and (fixing the path to my packages of course), it all works fine.

How can I fix this? How are other people getting around this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think I never managed to make relative path resolution work correctly in any of the type providers that I was involved with. If someone else can figure this out, that would be amazing.

Sooner or later, I just started to use `[<Literal>]` and `__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__` to give the type provider an absolute path:

```
[<Literal>]
let MyConfig = __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ + "/config.json"
type MyTPInstance = MyTp<myConfig = MyConfig>
```

This got a bit nicer with the `const` recently:

```
type MyTPInstance = MyTp<myConfig = const(__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ + "/config.json")>
```

It is still pretty ugly, but at least it works reliably.

Comment: Hallelujah. That works - thanks. BTW - where's the docs on the `const` keyword - is that F#4.1? Not seen it documented anywhere.

Comment: Doesn't even compile for me. The docs still show it as a reserved keword for future use.

Comment: Using F# Data, the following works for me `type B = CsvProvider<Sample = const(__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ + "/some.csv")>` when using F# Interactive version 14.0.23413.0

Comment: Can this trick be adapted to resolve the path to a sample file  for the JsonProvider? I tried a few variations but can't get it to compile.